# Why is my app crashing on certain devices?

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

I'm implementing the [Indriya Measurements library](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement) in my app as a dependancy:

```
implementation 'tech.units:indriya:2.0.2'
implementation 'javax.measure:unit-api:2.0'
implementation 'systems.uom:systems-parent:2.0.1'
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: tech.units.indriya.function.-$$Lambda$2_LlfYfHnss6CmMNCp0u4K-i1SA
    at tech.units.indriya.function.AbstractConverter.concatenate(AbstractConverter.java:177)
    at tech.units.indriya.AbstractUnit.transform(AbstractUnit.java:335)
    at tech.units.indriya.AbstractUnit.divide(AbstractUnit.java:480)
    at tech.units.indriya.AbstractUnit.divide(AbstractUnit.java:368)
    at tech.units.indriya.unit.Units.<clinit>(Units.java:231)
```

My app runs on some devices, but crashes on others, what is going on here?

Comment: Seems like the library uses lambdas which are a Java 8 feature. For using this in an Android app you have to use at least a Android Gradle Plugin v3.0: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support and AFAIR you need a certain minSdk value. What minSdk value has your app and on what device (Android API level) does the error occur?

Comment: I have already implemented java 8 requirements as per the docs. The error is occurring on an Android M device. And yes, I am using a v3.0+ Gradle plugin. The docs also write that you DON'T have to increase the min SDK version.

Answer (score 0):

Check your min SDK version.
you have to increase min ask version to ignore this issues.

Comment: The Android docs write that you don't have to increase the min SDK version?

Answer (score 0):

I can see in your post the error message is targeting the indriya library , try to update the version to latest and try again .